# how to know the type of class properties using typescript decorators

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, decorator

I want to know the type of class properties using typescript decorators

for example:

```
function Inject(constr : Function){
  //how to get engine property and its type!!! 
}

@Inject
class Car{

  constructor(private engine : Engine){}

}

class Engine{

  constructor(){}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you want? Are you going to use that decorator only for the Car class, or many kinds of classes?

Comment: You'll need to use the metadeta library, as explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata

Comment: Alex, I want to use it for many kinds of classes,